# Royal Mail SmartStamp csv format

Tags: csv

I'm trying to export addresses into csv format suitable for RoyalMails SmartStamp. Does anyone know the format for this? Is this just as you'd expect? (i.e. name, line1, line2, line3, county, country, postcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a response from RoyalMail. The order and appearance of fields is configurable and so the above format will work.